# span function in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I think that the **span** function is **Haskell** is to apply a predicate to a list, and return a tuple where the first element is elements in the list that satisfy that predicate and the second element is the reminder of the list.

And it works well when I put:
`span (<3) [1,2,4,5,6]`. It just returns in GHCI:
`([1,2], [4,5,6])`.

However, when I enter `span (>3) [1,2,4,5,6]`, it returns `([],[1,2,4,5,6])`. But I thought it should return `([4,5,6],[1,2])`. So I was wondering the reason of it .

Answer (score 14):

Your understanding of [span](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:span) is not entirely correct, this is what the official docs say:

> span, applied to a predicate p and a list xs,
>   returns a tuple where first element is longest **prefix** (possibly empty)
>   of xs of elements that satisfy p and second element
>   is the remainder of the list

(emphasis mine).

Hence, the predicate is applied to each element of the list starting from the beginning. This means that the predicate in

```
span (<3) [1,2,4,5,6]
```

is satisfied for the first two elements, and the result is

```
([1,2], [4,5,6])
```

But in this other example

```
span (>3) [1,2,4,5,6]
```

the first element of the list already doesn't satisfy the predicate, so the first element of the returned tuple will be an empty list.

Comment: Thanks! And I was just wondering if there is a function in Haskell that work in the way as I said, rather that prefix match?

Comment: Sure! See Willem's answer

Answer (score 9):

What you describe here is [**`partition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:partition). This is a function that for a given predicate will take a list, and make a 2-tuple where the first item is a list with items that satisfy the predicate, and the second item a list of items that do *not* satisfy the predicate. Indeed:

```
Prelude Data.List> partition (>3) [1,2,4,5,6]
([4,5,6],[1,2])
```

[**`span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:span) on the other hand makes a 2-tuple where the first item is the ***longest prefix*** of elements in the list that satisfy the predicate, and the second item is the list of remaining elements. Since for `span (>3) [1,2,4,5,6]`, the first item does *not* satisfy the predicate. The longest prefix is the empty list `[]`, and all elements of the given list, appear in the second item.

Answer (score 3):

Basically `span`'s complement is kind of [`break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:break). You might even need to read the part twice in the docs to understand the subtle difference between `break` and `span`.

> [`break`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:break), applied to a predicate p and a list xs, returns a tuple where
>   first element is longest prefix (possibly empty) of xs of elements
>   that **do not** satisfy p and second element is the remainder of the list:

So coming back to your question

```
λ> break (>3) [1,2,4,5,6]
([1,2],[4,5,6])
```

You may of course [`swap :: (a, b) -> (b, a)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Tuple.html) the tuple if that's essential. ie. `swap . break`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to view the `span` function is to see it as consisting of both `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` function. i.e it is the application of both `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` function.

And what are these two functions?

`takeWhile` according to the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:takeWhile)

> takeWhile, applied to a predicate p and a list xs, returns the longest prefix (possibly empty) of xs of elements that satisfy p:

Basically it keeps returning elements from the list as long as the predicate is true. This means If the first element fails the predicate `takeWhile` will return []

`dropWhile` on the other hand, according to the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:dropWhile)

> dropWhile p xs returns the suffix remaining after takeWhile p xs

Basically it keeps skipping elements from the list while the predicate returns true. Once the predicate returns false, the remaining elements in the list is returned.

To see if the statement I made above about `span` being the application of both `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` function, we can apply these function independently to see their results.

Using just `takeWhile`:

```
*Main Data.List> takeWhile (>3) [1,2,4,5,6]
[]
```

Using just `dropWhile`:

```
*Main Data.List> dropWhile (>3) [1,2,4,5,6]
[1,2,4,5,6]
```

Now using `span`

```
*Main Data.List> span (>3) [1,2,4,5,6]
([],[1,2,4,5,6])
```

The result confirms `span` is applying both `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`

Note that what you describe here:

> I think that the span function is Haskell is to apply a predicate to a list, and return a tuple where the first element is elements in the list that satisfy that predicate and the second element is the reminder of the list

Is the `partition` function as can be seen from the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:partition)